# Removed intersection regions in intervals in R

Tags: r

If I have intervals how can I find and remove the intersections in R. For example if I have:

```
start=c(5,9,1,2,14,18); end=c(10,12,3,4,16,20)
d<-cbind(start, end)
start end
 5  10
 9  12
 1   3
 2   4
14  16
18  20
```

I want the output to be

```
start end
 5   8
11  12
 1   1
 4   4
14  16
18  20
```

The first interval for example intersect with the second one then if the intersection is removed the first interval becomes (5,8) and the second (11,12) because 9 and 10 was included in both intervals so they should be removed. i.e tests the intervals if there is any intersection remove the intersection and return the intervals with the new start and end points. I'm wondering how can I code this in R.

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you want, what you mean for intersections? E.g. first line why `10` becomes `8`?

Comment: Thats because if you noticed the intervals (5,10) and (9,12) intersects then by removing the intersection which is 9 and 10 the first interval becomes (5,8) and the other becomes (11,12)

Comment: Please rephrase the question so that can be clearly understood.

Comment: which part is not clear for you?

Comment: Do you want intervals tested for intersection only by pairs, so that for example 1:3,9:12, 2:4,5:10 would not constitute an overlapping?

Answer (score 0):

This could be what you are looking for:

```
start <- c(5, 9, 1, 2, 14, 18)
end <- c(10, 12, 3, 4, 16, 20)
d <- cbind(start, end)

# create temporary data frame
temp <- d

# i loops among 1, 2 and 3, because 3 is half the length of vector start
for(i in seq(length(start) / 2)) {
  # both thisLine and nextLine will consider a pair of lines in the data frame
  # thisLine loops among 1, 3 and 5
  thisLine <- (2 * i) - 1
  # nextLine loops among 2, 4 and 6
  nextLine <- (2 * i)

  # if there is an intersection: meaning that start of nextLine is bigger than
  # the start of thisLine AND smaller than the end of thisline
  if((temp[nextLine,]["start"]) > temp[thisLine,]["start"] &
     (temp[nextLine,]["start"] < (temp[thisLine,]["end"]))) {
    # get initial end of thisLine
    initial_end_thisLine <- temp[thisLine,]["end"]
    # set new value for end of thisLine to be the start of nextLine - 1
    temp[thisLine,]["end"] <- temp[nextLine,]["start"] - 1
    # set new value for start of nextline to be the initial end of thisLine
    temp[nextLine,]["start"] <- initial_end_thisLine + 1
  }
}

# get the output
output <- temp
```

Please notice:

1- using a for loop is not very good in R. I just wanted to write an example of the solution. Better use the apply function family.

2- I understood your question, that you ONLY compare each pair of lines and look for intersections. If you also want to compare all lines with each other, that would need another solution.

3- data frame d is supposed to have even number of lines for this solution to work.

Comment: Than you Ferand.. how about if I want to compare intervals in two data frame; if I have d1 with x intervals and d2 with y intervals and I want to remove the intersection and in this case I need it line by line..

Comment: You are welcome! 
That would be much easier because then you could loop over all lines and not over pairs of them. And you wouldn't have to check if the number of lines is an even number.
The if condition would be almost the same, but thisLine would be for data frame d1 where nextLine would be in data frame d2.